# What is the maximum message payload size for a AWS-IoT core broker?

Tags: mqtt, iot, aws-iot

In the documentation [AWS Service Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html) the payload size limit is not clear for the IoT-Core service. Since we can [bridge local mosquitto to AWS IoT](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/iot/how-to-bridge-mosquitto-mqtt-broker-to-aws-iot/), I suppose that this last one should accept the max size of payload from mosquitto [witch is 256Mb](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mqtt-protocol-messages-overview/). So what is the max size (in terms of payload) that I can send to a broker in AWS-IotCore?

The reason for that question is that I dont want to create to many documents in my mongoDb. For that I am going to send hourly data and the document or the message payload will be much higher than sends for seconds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The maximum MQTT payload in AWS IoT Core is only 128kB.

> The payload for every publish request is limited to 128 KB. The AWS IoT service rejects publish and connect requests larger than this size.

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_iot (under `Message size`)

---

As of Feb 2020 the limits are documented at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/iot-core.html#iot-protocol-limits

Comment: Why is there an option in the nucleus component which says "maxMessageSizeInBytes" which can be increased to 2.5MB. Which one is the correct?