# Sending image as numpy array over MQTT to AWS IoT Core

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, image-processing, mqtt, aws-iot

I am capturing images from webcam and sending those images as numpy arrays to AWS IoT Core using AWS IoT Device Python SDK. At AWS IoT Core, this numpy array is transferred to a lamda function for image processing(via RESNET model).

But numpy arrays's size is too big to send over MQTT and thats why AWS IoT Core is not receiving it.

So my question is:

1. Is there a way to increase MQTT TX buffer size in SDK? I couldn't find any.
2. If not, then what is the best way to send a big numpy array over MQTT and receiving it?

Publishing code:

```
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    message['image'] = frame.tolist() #numpy array converted to list to make it work with json.dumps
    messageJson = json.dumps(message)
    myAWSIoTMQTTClient.publish(topic, messageJson, 0)
```

Frame numpy array:

```
[0:480] :[array([[156, 168, 20...ype=uint8), array([[155, 167, 20...ype=uint8), array([[144, 168, 20...ype=uint8), array([[144, 168, 20...ype=uint8), array([[138, 168, 20...ype=uint8), array([[138, 168, 20...ype=uint8), array([[149, 170, 20...ype=uint8), array([[151, 172, 20...ype=uint8), array([[156, 174, 20...ype=uint8), array([[156, 174, 20...ype=uint8), array([[153, 174, 20...ype=uint8), array([[152, 173, 20...ype=uint8), array([[153, 172, 20...ype=uint8), array([[154, 173, 20...ype=uint8), ...]
dtype:dtype('uint8')
max:222
min:0
shape:(480, 640, 3)
size:921600
```

Comment: How big is the array? MQTT has a max payload size of 256mb and AWS may have a smaller limit

Comment: I have added the array info in question

Comment: Yes, but how big after it's been converted to JSON? We are already at 5mb purely as raw bytes, converting it to a JSON representation could easily add one or more orders of magnitude.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57414725/what-is-the-maximum-message-payload-size-for-a-aws-iot-core-broker

Comment: Can you leverage JPEG compression and send a JPEG image and re-inflate it to a Numpy array at the receiving end? That will likely be 1/10th the size, or less. Or can you use YUV which would be half the size?

Comment: It would basically mean `cv2.imencode()` at the sending end and `cv2.imdecode()` (or PIL) at the receiving end.

Comment: I tried with PIL but i get error at json.dumps : Object of type Image is not JSON serializable

Comment: Why did you try with PIL when you are already using **OpenCV**? Surely `cv2.imencode()` would be simpler. Do you have control of the remote end?

Comment: Yes I can control remote end. But Even with cv2.imencode() I get same error  at json.dumps : Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable

Comment: JSON doesn't support encoding binary data (JPEGs) directly, so you'll need to base64 encode the data first to make it ASCII. That will add 30% to the size but if JPEG made your image only 10% of its original size, base64 encoding means it will still only be 13% of its original size.

Comment: How are you getting on? Any progress?

Comment: So I did JPEG compression using `cv2.imencode(".jpg", image, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 90])` but getting error `Invalid number of channels in input image:` when i am converting the encoded image to grayscale `cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`. why cant an encoded image be converted to grayscale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem a bit stuck. I don't know the AWS side of things, but can show you the imaging side. I am suggesting you convert your image `frame` (which is a Numpy array) into a JPEG image for transmission because that will take less bandwidth and result in smaller MQTT messages. However, a JPEG is binary so you can't send it as JSON unless you base64-encode it first. In my example below, I show a way to take your image (Numpy array) and:

- convert it to JPEG. Note that you could equally use PNG - especially if you want lossless - but that will be slower normally. Note you could equally use **PIL/Pillow** instead of **OpenCV**. Note that you can vary the quality too, which will affect size.
- base64-encode it
- convert to JSON

then I show the reverse process for the receiving end. The actual size/bandwith saving will depend on your image and how compressible it is and the quality loss you are prepared to accept, however I started with a 920kB image and actually represent it in 66kB of JSON.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np
from base64 import b64encode

# Get any old image, 640x480 pixels - corresponds to your "frame"
na = cv2.imread('start.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
print(f'DEBUG: Size as Numpy array: {na.nbytes}')

# Convert to "in-memory" JPEG
_, JPEG = cv2.imencode(".jpg", na, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 80])
print(f'DEBUG: Size as JPEG: {JPEG.nbytes}')
JPEG.tofile('DEBUG-original.jpg')

# Base64 encode
b64 = b64encode(JPEG)
print(f'DEBUG: Size as base64: {len(b64)}')
print(f'DEBUG: Start of base64: {b64[:32]}...')

# JSON-encode
message = { "image": b64.decode("utf-8") }
messageJSON = json.dumps(message)
print(f'DEBUG: Start of JSON: {messageJSON[:32]}')
```

**Sample Output**

```
DEBUG: Size as Numpy array: 921600
DEBUG: Size as JPEG: 49456
DEBUG: Size as base64: 65944
DEBUG: Start of base64: b'/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBD'...
DEBUG: Start of JSON: {"image": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAA
```

The receiver side will look like this:

```
### RECEIVER: All variables suffixed with '_r' to denote receiver ###

import cv2
import numpy as np
from base64 import b64decode

# Extract base64 from JSON
b64_r = json.loads(messageJSON)

# Extract JPEG-encoded image from base64-encoded string
JPEG_r = b64decode(b64_r["image"])

# Decode JPEG back into Numpy array
na_r = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(JPEG_r,dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

---

Note: If you want to convert to greyscale, you need to do that **before** JPEG-encoding:

```
# Convert to greyscale
grey = cv2.cvtColor(na, cv2. COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# JPEG-encode
_, JPEG = cv2.imencode(".jpg", grey, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 80])
```

---

**Keywords**: Python, MQTT, AWS, image processing, JSON, base64, encode, decode, bandwidth, minimise, minimize, reduce, prime.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I was really stuck with this problem. Your solution works perfectly.

Comment: Cool - glad it worked for you. Good luck with your project! Come back if you get stuck again. Questions, and answers, are free :-)